# MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN DOES NOT detect position

Tags: android, multi-touch, motionevent

I am a newbie in Android, lately I got this weird thing:

I have my customized View, in onTouchEvent method, i tried to detect multitouch gesture, but the MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN will always be triggered no matter my second finger touches the view or not.

It seems like ACTION_POINTER_DOWN doesn't behaves the same as ACTION_DOWN, since ACTION_DOWN will not be triggered if my finger didn't touch the view.

Please tell me what's wrong with that, is that a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working as intended.  Once you touch down, all touch events go to your view until a cancel or an up occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if i suppose to do that check, what i should do? Write extra code?

Comment: Check the screen position of the touch and see if its in the bounds of the view.  Or just don't care, depending on what you were trying to do (things like pinch to zoom should work regardless of where you put the 2nd finger).